# Android Studio Dialog Buttons out of Screen when using Wrap Content as LayoutParams

Tags: java, android

I Have a Dialog with a Custom layout in my layouts Folder, which Wraps its Content. If I pu tin a large Text into one of the TextFields, the Buttons on the Bottom dissapear. The Text itself is scrollable and everything else works just fine. I want the Buttons to stick to the Bottom of the Dialog and not disappear if the text is Too Large.
[Dialog without TextInput](https://gyazo.com/12d32d9a3a1fb42ab0954b13a782cad7), [Dialog with large Text](https://gyazo.com/13807c6ae184f91c8ad5b90aa8195851). Icannot post Pictures directly, therefore i just included Links.

I have already tried to change the Layout so the Buttons stick to the Bottom of the Layout instead of the TextView above them. Setting a fixed size isnt really an Option.

Layout of the Dialog Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_layout_rounded_16">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dialog_resource_title"
        style="@style/myEditTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/general_title_hint"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dialog_resource_description"
        style="@style/myEditTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/general_description_hint"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dialog_resource_cancel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialog_resource_title" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_resource_cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/general_cancel"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/dialog_resource_middle_line"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_resource_save"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/general_save"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/dialog_resource_middle_line" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/dialog_resource_middle_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


Initialisation of the Dialog:



        resourceDialog = new Dialog(context);

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_resource, null);

        this.resourceDialogTitle = v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_resource_title);
        this.resourceDialogDescription = v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_resource_description);
        this.resourceDialogCancel = v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_resource_cancel);
        this.resourceDialogSave = v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_resource_save);

        resourceDialog.setContentView(v);
        // Set Color of Root View (Otherwise white Background in the Corners)
        resourceDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

        // Getting the Display Metrics to set Size of Dialog
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        // Setting the Size
        resourceDialog.getWindow().setLayout((width - 128), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        resourceDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the buttons incide a linear layout and use a constraint option to constrain it to the bottom of the screen. For example

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <Button />

    <Button />
</LinearLayout>
```

--Edit--
I tried this and worked for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:paddingBottom="120dp"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/address"
            android:textColor="@color/black_1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I tried doing that as well as Constraining the Buttons to the Bottom but for some reason it still does not show the Button. I think thats probably because the Dialog expands outside of the Screen, so i need to set its max height to my ScreenSize. Maybe thatll work I´ll test ist

Comment: I will try it later, but that should work. Thanks in advance

Comment: Worked for me. Changed it so the Buttons are in the Nested ScrollView asl well, since I think that was it looks a little bit nicer. Thanks for the Wuick Help

Comment: Glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code to get a custom dialog:

XML Layout file **`(R.layout.dialog_custom_layout)`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:padding="@dimen/padding_8dp">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="User Details"
            android:gravity="center"/>

          <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email_EditText"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

           <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password_EditText"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_8dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Register"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**`Kotlin code to inflate custom layout:`**

```
val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
val customView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom_layout, null)
val btnRegister = customView.btnRegister
alertDialog.setView(customView)
val customDialog = alertDialog.create()
customDialog.show()
btnRegister.setOnClickListener {
 //perform registration
}
```

PS: You can change layout as per your requirement!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your EditText heigh to `0dp` from `wrap_content` (so it won't overlap your buttons) and constraint it to one of your buttons at the bottom part of the screen:

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/dialog_resource_description"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:hint="some text"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dialog_resource_cancel"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialog_resource_title" />
```

**Here is the full layout file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/dialog_resource_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:hint="general_title_hint"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/dialog_resource_description"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:hint="some text"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dialog_resource_cancel"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialog_resource_title" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dialog_resource_cancel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:text="general_cancel"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/dialog_resource_middle_line"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dialog_resource_save"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="general_save"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/dialog_resource_middle_line" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/dialog_resource_middle_line"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: That would result in a Dialog which is not auto Resizing with the text but has a fixed Size right? Because i want it to be small but expand on large Input